# xrandr settings forgotten after suspend/shutdown

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, suspend, xrandr, 22.04

I use xrandr to control my monitors e.g.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --output DP-0 --off
```

however since upgrading to 22.04, these settings are forgotten every time I suspend/resume or reboot.

lspci says `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080] (rev a1)`, apt says I have `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510` installed.

Why are xrandr settings not retained, and how can I fix this?

Comment: The settings brightness and gamma are also lost.